# creating a mysql query or job that automatically copies information frmo one table to another, not events

Tags: mysql

I am looking to create have an automatically re occurring script or job that copies data from one table to another table. I tried events but they dont seem to work given they stop copying data at random despite not having an end date. What other methods within mysql can I use to achieve this?

Comment: @akina sure here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65130535/mysql-phpadmin-events-stop-working-but-no-end-date-scheduled?noredirect=1#comment115149708_65130535

Comment: I am not using unix and the other does not work. What is there to continue?